# How to tell powershell not execute net command until the Exe installation finished?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell.
How to tell powershell not execute next command until the exe installation finished ?

Tried below two commands but dint help.
1. Start-Process  -NoNewWindow -Wait
2. ./example.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of:

[How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next)

[Start-Process -wait doesn't work when script is launched from command prompt opened with runas or as a scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790798/start-process-wait-doesnt-work-when-script-is-launched-from-command-prompt-ope)

[Run an application with PowerShell and wait until it is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908000/run-an-application-with-powershell-and-wait-until-it-is-finished)

Shop around next time before you ask, try any of these and consider deleting your question if any resolve your issue