# JAVA getRuntime().exec used to execute powershell script, Start-Process -wait no longer works

Tags: java, powershell, wait, runtime.exec, start-process

I am trying to execute a powershell script from my java console app, I was able to get this working with the below command:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start cd "+dir+" & start cmd.exe /k \"Powershell C:\\runscript.ps1 args\"",null,dir);
p.waitFor();
```

Inside my powershell script, i have the below snippet which gets called in a loop,

```
    Start-Process -FilePath $RunLocation -ArgumentList $args -wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput $OutputFile

$output = Get-Content $OutputFile| out-string   
    if(!($output.toLower().contains("failed"){
        Remove-Item $outLogFile
}
```

If I open command prompt, and copy exactly what I have in my `exec(...)` command, it runs great, however, when I run it in my Java application, it seems like the `-wait` in my powershell script is being ignored, and the next line  (which is checking and removing logs) is run, I've even gone to the length of adding a sleep for a few seconds in my powershell just after the `Start-Process`, this works but I'm hoping there is a better way.

The error i am getting is in the powershell script is below (this only happens when ive run it from my Java app, the -wait waits foor the start process to finsih before continuing when run directly from command prompt..):

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item D:\adhoc\logs\2016-06\output38844448.out: The process cannot access the file
'D:\adhoc\logs\2016-06\output38844448.out' because it is being used by another process.
At C:\runscript.ps1:91 char:3
+         Remove-Item $OutputFile
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\adhoc\log...4448.out:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Why is the `-wait` in my powershell script not working when I run it from my Java app using `runtime().exec`?

Comment: print that fired console script error so that you can get idea what is going wrong. Use this piece of code so that you can get error stream .

InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
 logger.info(line);

print that error so that we can give you proper solution regarding it.

Comment: Added more info to original question

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: Not sure what the cause is, but a better workaround was to modify the Powershell script, I found a previous post with a near indentical issue...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790798/start-process-wait-doesnt-work-when-script-is-launched-from-command-prompt-ope